# How to split comma separated strings and remove duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to grab some survey answers from another tab.
The answers were provided with a comma by default separation between options, and I need a formula that splits ranges and results in a list with no duplicates.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FILTER(B3:B9, B3:B9<>""),",")))))
```

If your other tab is `Sheet1` then use `Sheet1!B3:B9`

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this formula only gets the first row (B3) and doesn't consider the others :/ [result](https://prnt.sc/H-UXwq8gZmgs)

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Please see the updates answer

Comment: Works flawlessly, thanks a lot for your effort õ/